# Limit number of rows per [id]

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One with itemID and max. max value varies for each itemID. The second one with itemID and partID. I want mysql to show error when same itemID is being inserted more than max times in the second table.

Comment: The only way to do this is with a trigger.

Comment: ... or the other way, without a trigger.